# Express.js, apollo-server Playground, Route error "Not found" but it works

Tags: express, graphql, apollo-server, graphiql

I have a problem with my `express` app:

https://glitch.com/edit/#!/enthusiastic-velociraptor

When I navigate to `GET` `/graphql` it gives me Playground but in console I have a `Not found`

Why?

Reproducible with these steps:

- go to: https://glitch.com/edit/#!/enthusiastic-velociraptor
- see the code and open console
- go to: https://enthusiastic-velociraptor.glitch.me/graphql
- Graphql Playground works but in console you have "Not found" error!